# SwiftUI BarChart up and down animation

Tags: swiftui

I have I problem with animating bar charts. I want bars to change up and down when changing data just like in this [gif](https://r-graph-gallery.com/img/graph/288-animated-barplot-transition.gif). But `animation(.easeIn)` gives me some strange animation. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct ContentView: View {
    enum chartPeriods: Equatable{
        case week
        case month
    }
    @State var selectedChartPeriod: chartPeriods = .month
    
    struct BarData: Identifiable, Equatable {
        var type: String
        var count: Double
        var id = UUID()
    }
    var monthData: [BarData] = [
        .init(type: "Jan", count: 100),
        .init(type: "Feb", count: 200),
        .init(type: "Mar", count: 300)
    ]
    
    var weekData: [BarData] = [
        .init(type: "1", count: 3000),
        .init(type: "2", count: 2000),
        .init(type: "3", count: 4000),
        .init(type: "4", count: 1000)
    ]
    
    
    var data: [BarData] {
        switch selectedChartPeriod {
        case .month:
            return monthData
        case .week:
            return weekData
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Picker("", selection: $selectedChartPeriod.animation(.easeIn)){
                Text("Week")
                    .tag(chartPeriods.week)
                Text("Month")
                    .tag(chartPeriods.month)
            }
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
            
            
            Chart(data) {
                BarMark(
                    x: .value("Date", $0.type),
                    y: .value("Sales", $0.count)
                )
            }
            
            .chartYAxis(.hidden)
            .frame(height: 300)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Precisely spell 'some strange animation' so that you won't mislead anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `BarData` conformed to `Identifiable`, however, it will create a different `UUID` for each column. So, the Chart could not determine column positions since it had different ID. You have to fix the same ID to make the animation work.

```swift
struct BarData: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var type: String
    var count: Double
    var id: Int //<- Change it to Int for example
}

//Then mock data is something like
.init(type: "Jan", count: 100, id: 1),
.init(type: "Feb", count: 200, id: 2),
...
.init(type: "1", count: 3000, id: 1),
.init(type: "2", count: 2000, id: 2),
```

Output:

[image]